# jquery compare data-values against a range of numbers for if else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the [live site](http://tammymealplan.com)

I have a numeric range slider 
The HTML:

```
<div class="noUiSlider">
    <input type="hidden" name="grams_of_protein_min" value="0.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="grams_of_protein_max" value="50.00">
```

The values actually change based on the handles of the range slider.

What I want to do is use these numbers to compare the data-values of the divs that contain the posts. (easier to understand if you use dev tools in browser, look for data-protein="#")

Here is simplified html for a few of the divs I want to compare against the range.

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="post-62" class="type-post" data-protein="20"></div>
    <div id="post-54" class="type-post" data-protein="14"></div>
    <div id="post-51" class="type-post" data-protein="26"></div>
</div>
```

So the format I'm looking for is:

```
if data-protein-number is >= grams_of_protein_min value && <= grams_of_protein_max value then do this function {}

else do this {}
```

Sorry, it is much easier explaining it that way than wasting your time correcting my code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[data-protein]').each(function (item) {
    if(evaluateProtein($(item).attr('data-protein'))) {
        // Call function for if it does meet your criteria
    } else {
        //Call function for if it doesn't meet your criteria
    }
});
```

So basically all you have to write now is the "evaluateProtein" function. I dont know how you have things set up, so that is up to you, but this should be a good framework for you to get started with!